# Run ninja without rules

Tags: c++, ninja

I have a build where it would be easiest for now to just have unique build rules for each build target (eg object file and library). Is it possible to specify in the build.ninja-file what to do without first specifying a rule for it.

For example (toy syntax)

```sh
build this_file: depends_on_this.o depends_on_that.o  - gcc argumentss_to_use files.o etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual I found out a way to do this a minute after asking.

We  could just forward the whole command as a variable

```
rule run
  command = $cmd
  

build log.txt: run
  cmd = echo $hello >> log.txt
```